# dill/pickle issue with built-in function

Tags: python, pickle, dill

When using `dill` to serialize a class:

```
import dill, pickle

class project(object):
    def __init__(self, name='', folder='', user_id='', version=-1 ):
        self.name, self.folder, self.user_id, self.version = name, folder, user_id, version
# Other code, not shown, since Big class .......

dill.dump(proj1, open('test_dill.pkl', 'w'), byref=False )
```

I get this message :

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in function raw_input>: it's not the same object as __builtin__.raw_input


  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 236, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 642, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 835, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\dill\dill.py", line 993, in save_builtin_method
    StockPickler.save_global(pickler, obj)

  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\pickle.py", line 759, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))

PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in function raw_input>: it's not the same object as __builtin__.raw_input
```

Am not sure than built-in functions can be modified by the code...
It sounds mysterious.

Comment: There's no `raw_input` in your code...perhaps it's lost in the `...`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. After removing `......` and creating a `proj1` object, this code worked fine (at least on python 2). Please post something runnable that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: raw_input is built in class, not shown in the class code.
What is the purpose of raw_input ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm the `dill` author.  The different settings (such as `byref`) are used to modify the types of objects that are included in the `dump`.  `pickle`, and thus `dill`, use recursive object serialization, which means when an object refers to another object, it may (or may not) serialize it, based on the serialization settings.  `pickle` typically serializes functions and classes *by reference* (`byref=True`) which means they are only serialized on import and by name. `dill` has several settings, such as `byref=False` (which serializes function and class objects instead of by reference).  There is also `recurse`, which deals with how global references are serialized -- `recurse=False` serializes all the globals as a dict, while `recurse=True` serializes only the referenced items in globals and items that those items refer to and so on.

In short, whatever you are serializing has some global references, which trigger recursive serialization until it hits something `dill` can't pickle.

Here are some things you can try:

1. Separate objects in the file into separate files -- this allows you to rely more on pickling by reference.
2. Use different settings, such as `recurse=True`, to change which objects `dill` tries to serialize with your target object. You can set the settings globally with `dill.settings`.
3. Add serialization helper methods to your class, that inform `pickle` how to serialize your class.
4. Refactor your class (somehow, since I can't see the contents of it) to avoid serialization problems.

It's hard to answer more in depth as you haven't posted a working example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: Error message says: "PicklingError: Can't pickle <built-in function raw_input>: it's not the same object as __builtin__.raw_input".

it means that __builtin__  method has been changed during the process of generation my class.

How can I change the definition of Built in class ?  (it looks weird).

Comment: @Tensor: Not true. The most common reason for seeing that error is that the object (`builtin.raw_input` in this case) is not actually defined at that namespace and has been aliased there by some means.  It's a very common pickling error, as object aliasing is done a lot.  This is one of the reasons that python 3 introduced the `qualname` attribute -- which unfortunately `dill` does not yet leverage.

Comment: It's hard to say more than I have above, without seeing your code. You don't provide a simplified example that demonstrates what you are seeing, then you will likely only be provided with abstract answers.

Comment: `dill` does also include several pickle error detection tools, within `dill.detect`.  you might also try those to help diagnose your error.